# Create column that is filled automatically (depending on another columns)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

I am working with a SharePoint list that contains information about new employees. One column represents the StartDate, another column the EndDate (according the contract).

In my company we have two kinds of identification card, one is for employees that will stay maximum 30 days (visitor pass) and another one is for employees who will stay longer (permanent ID).

In this SharePoint list I want the field `ID type` to be filled automatically. I tried to add this code in the formula section of `ID Type` (after you click on edit column):

```
IF((DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],"D")>30; [ID Type] = "permanent ID"; [ID Type] = "visitor pass")
```

Unfortunately, the SharePoint list does not save this formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements, you have to create a column with "Calculated" data type.

You can use the formula like below in calculated column:

```
=IF(DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],"D")>30,"Permanent ID","Visitor Pass")
```

Follow steps given in my answer to create a calculated column in a list at: [Formula does not work for SharePoint/Lists](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/formula-does-not-work-for-sharepoint-lists/m-p/3598229/highlight/true#M62834)

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on language or regional settings on your site). In that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`) at all places in above formula.
2. You cannot use "calculated value" option of existing columns as this option cannot reference other columns in list in formula. So, you have to create a column with "calculated" data type for referencing other columns in list in calculated formula.